# Controlling load order on dynamically loaded scripts

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a basic [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) which loads some assets (mostly stylesheets and scripts) on demand.

The loader looks like this (this is a simplified version):

```
class ModuleXLoader
    constructor: ->
        @scripts = [
            'https://www.example.com/assets/js/script1.js',
            'https://www.example.net/assets/js/script2.js',
            'https://www.example.org/assets/js/script3.js'
        ]
        @scriptsLoaded = 0

    load: (@callback) ->
        document.head.appendChild @.scriptTag url for url in @scripts

    scriptTag: (url) ->
        domElement = document.createElement 'script'
        domElement.type = 'text/javascript'
        domElement.onload = (event) =>
            console.log event.currentTarget.src # This logs the script's URL
            @.callback() if ++@scriptsLoaded is @scripts.length and typeof @callback is 'function'
        domElement.src = url
        return domElement
```

So, when I need to load `ModuleX` I do:

```
loader = new ModuleXLoader()
loader.load () =>
   console.log 'All scripts have been loaded, let\'s do stuff!'
```

This appends the required scripts to my `<head>` and everything works as expected.

---

The **problem** appears when there are some dependencies between the required scripts. Depending on the response time of every CDN (let's say `example.com`, `example.net`...) scripts are loaded in *random* order so, sometimes I got the classic:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: *ModuleXDependency* is not defined

Of course, I tried different ordenations on my `@scripts` array, but it doesn't mater.

I was thinking on some kind of *semaphores* implementation:

```
@scripts =
    script1:
        url: 'https://www.example.com/assets/js/script1.js'
        requires: 'script3'
        loaded: false
    script2: # etc.


domElement.onload = (event) =>
    # This is not a real implementation but kind of pseudocode idea...
    @wait() while not @scripts[@scripts['script1'].requires].loaded
```

But to be honest it feels too dirty to go this way, so I was wondering if maybe someone has a better idea...

Comment: Using AMD is not an options for you I assume? Everything else will probably impact the performance. But the way is clear: Build a dependency graph and then process it. Dynamically added scripts are executed differently in different browsers. But they might execute `async` so no way to control it.

Comment: Hi @Lux, I'm not familiar with AMD. Could you provide a link to some documentation, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to use a module definition like `AMD`. Maybe you should consider to use an existing module loader like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org). Here will you also find documentation about `AMD`. Maybe read the [whyAMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) text.

If you want an absolut minimum loader and load the scripts yourself you could checkout [`loader.js`](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js).

The idea about AMD is basically that you define your modules like this:

```
define('dep', [], function() {
  // here goes your code
  return {};
});

define('mymodule', ['dep'], function(dep) {
  // here goes your code.
});
```

A loader like `loader.js` or `require.js` will basically build a graph of these modules, and then when you do something like `require('mymodule')` it will know that it has to call `dep` first, and then will inject the result into the `mymodule` as the first parameter.

`loader.js` will basically just do this, while `require.js` has the ability load load the modules over the network.

However with both you can just manually load the script tags, wait until all are loaded, and then call your entry point.

The important thing is that it does not matter in which order the calls to `define` are executed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create bundles, just concatenate all the dependencies that you will be loading at the same time into one minified js file, a "bundle".  Load that one file instead of 3. it will solve your dependency order problem and offer other improvements as well.

Comment: You're right. This is a possible solution. Anyway I'd like to know if this can be done in another way... Thank you!